# How to create a gradle task that will execute bootRun with a specific profile?

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I essentially want to create a task in gradle that executes the command

```
gradle bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

This command does exactly what I want it to do if executed from the command line but I have had no luck trying to use [type:Exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091805/executing-commands-with-gradle) on a task and also no luck passing in [System properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367507/how-to-pass-system-property-to-gradle-task)

I don't really want to make this into an external command that the user needs to know about to run. I would like it to show up under tasks/other.

My closest attempt so far:

```
task bootRunTest() {
    executable "gradle"
    args "-Dspring.profiles.active=test bootRun"
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task I was trying to create wound up being this:

```
task bootRunTest(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask, dependsOn: 'build') {
    group = 'Application'
    doFirst() {
        main = project.mainClassName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'test'
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i change webapp folder path for this particular task?

Comment: This *must* be after `dependencies` block.

Comment: has to be `org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun` for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you set the properties for the task you wish to run, in this case bootRun

add inside of **Build.gradle**

```
bootRun {
        systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "test,qa,ect"
}
```

Then from the command line

```
gradle bootRun
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "test"` not `"test,qa,ect"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by setting the **OS** variable, **SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE**, to the specific profile.

For eg:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev gradle clean bootRun
```